# Where can I find mavenized hibernate-annotations 3.6.10

Tags: hibernate, maven, hibernate-annotations

I'm trying to update my project to use last hibernate 3.6.10.Final release but I can't find a hibernate-annotations that contains the dependency hibernate-core 3.6.10.Final
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-annotations

Where can I find it?
It isn't the first time I notice the lack of versions. What is the logic?

Answer (score 3):

I believe that from Hibernate 3.6.0 onwards the hibernate-annotations were merged into hibernate-core.

You should then try updating hibernate-core version as required and removing hibernate-annotations.

Comment: Yup, Actually they done horrible thing. Instead they should add a dependency to hibernate-annotations.

Answer (score 1):

The Hibernate project does a very poor job of publishing artifacts to Maven Central.   If you want them to publish the 3.6 binaries to Central I'd suggest asking the project why they haven't published artifacts to the JBoss repository manager which is automatically synchronized with Central.